# Can there be an electric current drawn through a resistor from just one terminal of a battery?

Tags: electric-circuits

The question will appear a little more sincere from the attached diagram.

Will there be any flow of charge at all once the switch S is closed?
If yes, then

1. by what mechanism?
2. for how long?
3. What will be the total amount of charge flown?

What I think:

There will be some charge flowing through the resistor till the negative terminal of the battery cannot hold anymore negative charges. There the charge production mechanism of the battery will stop ionizing the electrolyte.

But I am not confident of my own concept and interested to know from someone who knows better.[image]

P.S. What happens to the situation

1. if the battery is replaced by an AC generator?

and then

2. the resistor is unearthed?

Comment: current is *through*, voltage is *across*.

Answer (score 0):

What you've drawn is an open circuit. If you initially have the switch open and then close it, there may be some slight momentary flow of current due to the fact that there are always very small stray capacitances between various parts of your circuit, including a very small stray capacitance from the negative terminal of your battery to ground which would complete the circuit. We're talking extremely small capacitances here, though. So for your questions (2) and (3), the answers would be "very short" and "virtually nil", respectively. You would have to calculate how much stray capacitance you have from the negative terminal of your battery to ground to get a numerical answer.

As for your PS(1) question, yes, stray capacitances can be very important at high frequencies and can actually dominate circuit behavior. The higher the frequency gets, the more important stray capacitances and stray inductances become. As for question PS(2), disconnecting the resistance from ground would probably decrease the amount of stray capacitance since the Earth would no longer acting as one side of the capacitor.

Comment: I agree with your explanation. However, I think there's more to it than that. Inside the battery as the terminals have charges and the grounding of the resistor allows electron to flow from the earth to the +ve terminal to neutralize some charges. To keep the potential difference same across the terminals, the chemical reaction will produce some more +ve and -ve charge pairs till the -ve terminal reaches its full capacity as no -ve charge escapes that terminal. Is this right?

Comment: For the purposes of analyzing the schematic diagram you drew, it is sufficient to treat the battery as a "black box" which provides the voltage V by whatever mechanism. If you want to examine what a chemical battery is actually doing then, yes, there will be some chemical activity as a result of the fact that some electrons have moved out from the negative terminal of the battery into the wire because the wire does form a small capacitance with ground.